# image upload in codeigniter giving error

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I am upload an image in one my form but its always giving me an error like

> "A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message:
>   Undefined index: vimage Filename: controllers/vouchers.php Line
>   Number: 42"

**My View File code :**

```html
<?php echo form_open_multipart(site_url("promotions/add_item/"), array("class" => "form-horizontal","id"=>"addItem")) ?>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Show on</label>
                              <div class="col-sm-3">
                                Artist Directory : <input type="checkbox" name="artist_dir" value='1'>
                              </div>  
                              <div class="col-sm-3">
                                Highlight : <input type="checkbox" name="highlight" value='1'>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Title</label>
                              <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Title">
                              </div>
                            </div>
                             <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Image</label>
                              <div class="col-sm-9">
                                  <input type="file" name="pro_image">
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Description</label>
                              <div class="col-sm-9">
                                  <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="description" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
                                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          
                        <?php echo form_close() ?>
```

**My Controller Code :**

```html
<pre>
 public function add_item(){
        
            $this->load->library('upload');
             
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('title','Title','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('description','Description','required');
            
            print_r($_FILES['pro_image']); 
            if ($_FILES['pro_image']['size'] > 0) {
                    $this->upload->initialize(array( 
                    "upload_path" => './uploads/',
                    "overwrite" => FALSE,
                    "encrypt_name" => TRUE,
                    "remove_spaces" => TRUE,
                    "allowed_types" => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg",
                ));


                 if (!$this->upload->do_upload('vimage')) {
                     $this->upload->display_errors();
                 }

                 $data = $this->upload->data();
                 echo 'img : '.$img = $data['file_name'];
            } 
            exit;
            
            if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){
                echo '<div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-danger"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button><small>'.  validation_errors().'</small></div>';
            }
            else {
                $title = $this->input->post('title');
                $description = $this->input->post('description');
                $artist_dir = $this->input->post('artist_dir');
                $highlight = $this->input->post('highlight');
                $this->promotions_model->add_item($title, $description,$artist_dir,$highlight);
            }
    }
    </pre>
```

please let me know what i am doing wrong here

Comment: Did you load library `upload`?

Comment: What `var_dump($_FILES);` shows?

Comment: yes i have add upload library $this->load->library('upload'); when i do var_dump($_FILES); its shows me null

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  if ($_FILES['vimage']['size'] > 0) {
    $this->load->library('upload');
     $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options());
                    $this->upload->do_upload();
                    $fileName = $_FILES['vimage']['name'];

    private function set_upload_options()
      { 
      // upload an image options
             $config = array();
             $config['upload_path'] = './upload/'; //give the path to upload the image in folder
             $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
              $config['max_size'] = '0';
             $config['overwrite'] = FALSE;
      return $config;
      }
```

For more read this [Link](http://w3code.in/2015/09/upload-file-using-codeigniter/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (!empty($_FILES['vimage']))
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    //$config['max_size'] = '102400';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config['overwrite'] = FALSE;
    $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
    $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('vimage'))
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $this->upload->display_errors());
        //redirect('controller/method');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Image Has been Uploaded');
        //redirect('controller/method');
        $img = $data['file_name'];
    }

}
```

Comment: hi disha when i try this code its giving me an error like "
Severity: Notice
Message:  Undefined variable: img
Filename: controllers/vouchers.php
Line Number: 60"
and line numner 60 is : $img = $data['file_name']; this

Comment: okay then how can i add the image path in database? can you guide me

Comment: just add image name only. and in view `<img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>.'uploads/'.<?php echo #### ?> "`

Comment: ### will be tha image name of your image which store in DB

Comment: i have try that but still not going for upload

Comment: i have got the issue, issue i i am open form in modal window so 
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url().'vouchers/add_item' ?>" enctype='multipart/form-data' class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="addItem"> if i remove "id="addItem" then image upload is work fine but my form validation do not work
so in form we can not add form id can you plz give me any idea for that

Answer (score 0):

Please check first,

> print_r(_FILES);

If you get files array then you can use below code for uploading image.

```
function do_upload()
{
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_size']    = '100';
$config['max_width']  = '1024';
$config['max_height']  = '768';

// You can give Image formats if you want to upload any video file.

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
{
$error = array('error' = $this->upload->display_errors());

// uploading failed. $error will holds the errors.
}
else
{
$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

// uploading successfull, now do your further actions
}
}
```

Comment: Hi i have try with this when i do print_r(_FILES); its coming null

Comment: So problem is in your form please check your form you did not get any data in your controller from your form.

Comment: in my form i have 3 other fields as well in that i am getting the value and i can insert in to database but only in this field i am getting like that

Comment: can you please share your code here for all model , view and controller ?

Comment: can you give me your email id so i can send you in there?

Comment: sorry, i am in company in here not allowed to share any information regarding the company...  if you attach any file here so i  will check it. Thanks

Comment: i have set my new code with full function and view file plz check it.

Comment: Hello , i have  setup your code in my system and it is working for me . i get array of file . let i shre my code also to you.              Array ( [pro_image] => Array ( [name] => userm_1445941439.png [type] => image/png [tmp_name] => D:\wamp\tmp\php7DDC.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 627207 ) )

Comment: oh okay then dont know why in my code its not showing is there anything that i have to set in codeigniter config?

Comment: i have got the issue, issue i i am open form in modal window so 
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url().'vouchers/add_item' ?>" enctype='multipart/form-data' class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="addItem"> if i remove "id="addItem" then image upload is work fine but my form validation do not work
so in form we can not add form id can you plz give me any idea for that

Comment: Hello for form validation you can use class or name i think not need to only id for validation

Comment: can you give ma any demo how can i do validation in edit form.

Comment: Example:  $().ready(function () {
        $(".formToValidate").validate();
        $(".checkBox").each(function (item) {
            $(this).rules("add", {
                required: true,
                minlength:3
            });
        });
    });

Comment: ths issue is confict with this "event.preventDefault();" if i comment this line in ajax code then working but my other code not working then like when edit success its return valid message then validation not showing properly like that.
is there any other things that i can use instead of that

Answer (score 0):

I have added your code in my system it's working for fine for me.

```
public function add(){
        $this->load->library('upload');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('url');
         print_r($_FILES);die; 

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('title','Title','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('description','Description','required');


            if ($_FILES['pro_image']['size'] > 0) {
                    $this->upload->initialize(array( 
                    "upload_path" => './uploads/',
                    "overwrite" => FALSE,
                    "encrypt_name" => TRUE,
                    "remove_spaces" => TRUE,
                    "allowed_types" => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg",
                ));


                 if (!$this->upload->do_upload('vimage')) {
                     $this->upload->display_errors();
                 }

                 $data = $this->upload->data();
                 echo 'img : '.$img = $data['file_name'];
            } 
            exit;

            if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){
                echo '<div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-danger"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button><small>'.  validation_errors().'</small></div>';
            }
            else {
                $title = $this->input->post('title');
                $description = $this->input->post('description');
                $artist_dir = $this->input->post('artist_dir');
                $highlight = $this->input->post('highlight');
                $this->promotions_model->add_item($title, $description,$artist_dir,$highlight);
            }


    }
```

Comment: i am still getting the same error and when i do print_r($_FILES) its coming null.
what is the issue is there anything i have to set in config?

Comment: Now please try to change form use simple form like  <form action="promotions/add_item/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: Hello i have do it as per this but still i am getting the same error <form action="<?php echo base_url() ?>promotions/add_item/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" id="addItem">

Comment: i have got the issue, issue i i am open form in modal window so 
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url().'vouchers/add_item' ?>" enctype='multipart/form-data' class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="addItem"> if i remove "id="addItem" then image upload is work fine but my form validation do not work
so in form we can not add form id can you plz give me any idea for that